# Overwrote master with another branch completely when trying to merge, how to revert it?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I wanted to merge two branches into one, however instead I overwrote it.

On github desktop I went toolbar branch -> "Merge into current branch" on master, chose branch A then pushed it, and now it's as if branch A has been copied over into master without any trace at all of the previous master branch.

How do I revert it? There's no commit history of the merge at all & cant find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Run `git reflog master` in a terminal, you will see a history of the previous states of your `master` branch.

---

To revert to a target commit :

from a clean worktree (e.g: `git status` indicates that there are no modified files and nothing to commit), you can use `git reset --hard`:

```
# switch to your master branch:
git checkout master

# move it to its previous state:
git reset --hard <sha>
```